# How can we inspect all React components and their state in React Dev tools even in production mode?

Tags: reactjs

[image]Production mode is supposed to contain no information that the app is a React one. But I am able to inspect them on React Dev tools. How is it possible?

Comment: _Production mode is supposed to contain no information that the app is a React one_ - what makes you think that? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @TomFenech added

Comment: Where in that image does it support the claim that production mode is supposed to contain no information that the app in a React one?

Comment: How is React Dev tools able to reconstruct all the components from compiled code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Production mode does contain information that the app is a react one. The difference between production and development mode is based on your preferences. They might not contain any difference at all during some development.

In production sometimes the only difference might be that the code has been [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) or [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) has been done. So basically you can inspect all react components in production mode also.

Comment: isn't that info and overhead? how can i disable that?

Comment: You can't disable front end code. That is the code that is read by the browser. You will have to send it anyway and all the data in the browser can be read by the browser.